# python cmd module context based completion

Tags: python, autocomplete, python-cmd

In python `cmd` module, when I press the TAB button, I get the list of possible commands that are available and that I have defined in my `cmd.Cmd` class. 
My question is whether it is possible to show a set of commands based on the context like in a Cisco router CLI for instance?

Comment: What is python `cmd`?

Comment: @PeterWood  may be this https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html

Comment: What is the *context*? If *context* is the command to complete, take a look at @oxfn answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with this lib, but [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop) says

> If completion is enabled, completing commands will be done automatically, and completing of commands args is done by calling `complete_foo()` with arguments text, line, begidx, and endidx. text is the string prefix we are attempting to match: all returned matches must begin with it. line is the current input line with leading whitespace removed, begidx and endidx are the beginning and ending indexes of the prefix text, which could be used to provide different completion depending upon which position the argument is in.

So, may be you can implement context based completion in `complete_foo` function

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question. One can use nested interpreters, so a nested interpreter is another interpreter object that will have its own commands, this way each context can be modeled by a nested interpreter. Here is a nice explanation and example:

[object inheritance and nested cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822164/object-inheritance-and-nested-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like Cisco take a look at ishell,

> ishell helps you to easily create an interactive shell for your application. It supports command completion, dynamic arguments, a command history, and chaining of commands.

https://github.com/italorossi/ishell

There's a cisco like cli example at https://github.com/italorossi/ishell/blob/master/examples/cisco.py
[image: Cisco ishell example]

PS: I'm the author.