# python Cmd module autocompletion error in nested interpreters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a debug console for the main console I'm writing using Cmd module.

The debug console should have all the main console attributes and ontop some more extentions used for debug and advanced users.

The best answer to fir my needs was the second answer of the following post:
[object inheritance and nested cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822164/object-inheritance-and-nested-cmd)

My implementation currently looks like this:

```
class MainConsole(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
       cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

    def do_something(self, line):
       print "do something!"
       return

    def do_something2(self, line):
       print "do something2!"
       return    

class SubConsole1(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self, maincon):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.maincon = maincon
        self.register_main_console_methods()

    def register_main_console_methods(self):
        main_names = self.maincon.get_names()
        for name in main_names:
            if (name[:3] == 'do_') or (name[:5] == 'help_') or (name[:9] == 'complete_'):
                self.__dict__[name] = getattr(self.maincon, name)
```

**Observation:**

When I hit "help", I indeed see all the upper console methods and I'm able to invoke them.

**Problem:**

The autocompletion of the actual commands is not available.

The expected behaviour of the shell when hitting "some" and tab would be to autocomplete it to "something". This doesn't happen.

When I tried to debug the issue, I found out that `self.get_names()` method which is used by the `self.completenames()` function returns the list of methods before the registration.

So what's actually happening is that the newly added methods are "removed" from the nested console, although I can invoke them.

I'd love some insights on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem by extending `get_names` method

```
import cmd

class MainConsole(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self,console_id):
       cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
       self.console_id = console_id
    def do_something(self, line):
       print "do something!",self.console_id
       return

    def do_something2(self, line):
       print "do something2!",self.console_id
       return    

class SubConsole1(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self, maincon):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.maincon = maincon
        self.register_main_console_methods()

    def do_super_commands(self,line):
        print "do supercommand",self.maincon

    def register_main_console_methods(self):
        main_names = dir(self.maincon)
        for name in main_names:
            for prefix in 'do_','help_','complete_', :
                if name.startswith(prefix) and name not in dir(self):
                    self.__dict__[name] = getattr(self.maincon, name)

    def get_names(self):
        result = cmd.Cmd.get_names(self)
        result+=self.maincon.get_names()
        return result

SubConsole1(MainConsole("mainconsole")).cmdloop()
```

it is not guaranteed to work on subsequence version of python as it is undocumented behavior of python 2.7

**EDIT**: replacing the subclassing method by mainconsole as a member as required in comment

**EDIT 2**: don't replace the existing methods in SubConsole to keep method as do_help

Comment: Hi @Xavier, thanks for the answer. This solution will not work for me since the main console holds a client instance with a connection to server and some logic. So I'd really want to utilize the main console instance.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However now the local "do_" methods are not exists on the help menu (although can be invoked), and its help isn't available.

Comment: What happened is that the `do_help` method was replaced so the one invoked was the `MainConsole` one